# Creating a co-clustering for the edge node triangle adjancy matrix in R/Python

Tags: python, r, graph, machine-learning, igraph

I have the following edge (rows) node (cols) triangle adjancy matrix in which we have a one in each entry if the edge belongs to a triangle. I want to do the co-clustering on this matrix (but as you see it's not a conventional adjancy matrix). Any though if there are already some coclustering functions in R? I know that R includes cocluster function in `blockcluster` but couldn't find a well-presented example to work with it. Python/R code/packages should work for me.

Here's the graph

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(15, .6)

73 x 15 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 [1,] 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . .
 [2,] . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
 [3,] 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
 [4,] . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
 [5,] . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . .
 [6,] . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . .
 [7,] 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . .
 [8,] . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . .
 [9,] 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . .
[10,] . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . . .
[11,] . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . . .
[12,] . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . . .
[13,] 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . .
[14,] . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . . .
[15,] . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . . .
[16,] . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . . .
[17,] . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
[18,] . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . . .
[19,] 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . .
[20,] . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . . .
[21,] . . . . 1 . . . 1 . . . . . .
[22,] . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . . .
[23,] . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . .
[24,] . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . . .
[25,] 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
[26,] . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
[27,] . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . . .
[28,] . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . . .
[29,] . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . .
[30,] . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . .
[31,] . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . . . .
[32,] . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . . .
[33,] . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . . .
[34,] . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . .
[35,] . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . . .
[36,] . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . .
[37,] . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . . . .
[38,] . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . . .
[39,] . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . . .
[40,] . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . .
[41,] . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . . .
[42,] . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . .
[43,] . . . . . . 1 . . . . 1 . . .
[44,] . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 . . .
[45,] . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . .
[46,] . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . . .
[47,] 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
[48,] . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
[49,] . . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 . .
[50,] . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1 . .
[51,] . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1 . .
[52,] . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . .
[53,] . . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 . .
[54,] . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . .
[55,] . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1 . .
[56,] 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
[57,] . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
[58,] . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 .
[59,] . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1 .
[60,] . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 .
[61,] . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 .
[62,] . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1 .
[63,] . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 .
[64,] . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 .
[65,] . 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
[66,] . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1
[67,] . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . . 1
[68,] . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . . 1
[69,] . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1
[70,] . . . . . . . 1 . . . . . . 1
[71,] . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . . 1
[72,] . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . 1
[73,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1
```

** `cocluster` function didn't work on this matrix even after I made it like a standard matrix. So I am not sure if I can do the coclustering on edge-node triangle adjacency matrix as well or not or just the standard adjacency matrix. Please ask me questions before voting down this question or deciding to close it and I will try to elaborate as much as possible.

Comment: I don't think that the `coclustering` function is included in `igraph`: http://igraph.org/r/doc/.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I mentioned the `cocluster` from this link http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/blockcluster/html/cocluster.html It would have been really great if `igraph` had a `cocluster` function

Comment: Please provide more information about why `coclustering` fails for your matrix (i.e. what does it print when it fails?). I have just tried `coclustering(as.matrix(m), datatype="binary", nbcocluster=c(3,3))` where `m` was a sparse matrix and it worked perfectly fine for me. Note that you need `as.matrix(m)` because `cocluster` seems to work on dense matrices only.

Answer (score 1):

There is biclustering in scikit-learn (same as co-clustering)

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/biclustering.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/bicluster_newsgroups.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_spectral_biclustering.html

I don't know the R part of your question

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)

library(blockcluster)

set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(15, .6)
m <- get.adjacency(g)
m <- as.matrix(m)

cc <- cocluster(m, datatype="binary", nbcocluster=c(3,3))
```

it works well.